# How to extract multiple elements from XPath Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I made this XPath

```
alo1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='txt-block']/span/a/span").text
print(alo1)
```

but the problem is: i'm getting only the first element, but there is 3 or 4 elements with the same XPath, and i wanted then all.

From page to page the number of elements change from 0 to 4.

How can i do it?

And other thing, do you think is possible to make another XPath? I'm trying to get the name of the producers of the films.

EDIT:

I have a second difficulty. I'm passing this result to an excel sheet, but it needs to be in one line to be printed there, or else will only print the last one. How can it be done? ,

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("A Test Sheet")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4854442/?ref_=wl_li_tt')
labels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='txt-
block']/span/a/span")
for label in labels:
   print (label.text)
ws.write(x-1,1,label.text)
wb.save("sinopses.xls")
```

The website for reference: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4854442/?ref_=wl_li_tt

Comment: You should ask only one question and not to change the question after answers posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

`FindElement` always give only one result , even if the locator matches more than one , it automatically takes the first one.

If locator gives more than one matching result and you want all of them then you should go for `findElements`

For the second question:

```
labels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='txt-
block']/span/a/span")
result = ''
for label in labels:
   result += label.text
   print (result)
ws.write(x-1,1,result)
wb.save("sinopses.xls")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get them all at once, and then get text for each element:

```
alos = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='txt-block']/span/a/span")

for alo in alos:
  print alo.text
```

Comment: Now i have a second dificulty. I'm passing this result to an excel sheet, but it needs to be in one line to be printed there, or else will only print the last one. How can it be done?